# Creating a search form in html

Tags: html, url

I'm trying to create a search form using a simple html page. However, I cannot get it to process my results. I'm a newbie to coding, I'm unaware of certain terms here. So forgive my ability to frame a proper question here.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
http://www.example.com/#A/XYZ
```

This is my code:

```
<b>whats my dns</b><br/><br/><form method="get" action="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank"> <input type="text"  name="#A/" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" /></form>
```

My results on using the above code:

```
https://www.example.com/?%23A%2F=XYZ
```

Basically I'm trying to create a search engine for an external site. Here XYZ is what I want to search.

Is this possible just by using HTML? If so, how?
If not, is there any other way I can achieve this without using server sided scripting like PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible just by using HTML?

No.

> If not, is there any other way I can achieve this without using server sided scripting like PHP?

In theory, you could write the search engine in JavaScript and then deliver it and your entire database of search terms to the client.

A server side solution would generally be prefered though.